# Scope is not defined, calling functions in Angularjs module

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to call a method when creating a new variable (targetPath) which then calls other methods to get all the data needed to download a video to the correct directory on local android storage. However I am having trouble calling the methods as my method called either gets undefined or if I used $scope.callMethod, scope gets undefined.

```
var targetPath = scope.getFilePath();

//Gets the URL of where to download from
$scope.getURL = function () {

//Whatever URL we want
var url = "http://static.videogular.com/assets/videos/videogular.mp4";
return url;
}


//Gets the filename of any URL we download from
$scope.getFileName = function () {


//Splits the URL
var filename = scope.getURL().split("/").pop();

return filename;


}


//This function is used to get the directory path so we can use it for other functions
$scope.getFilePath = function () {

//Use this code for internal file download
var targetPath = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory + scope.getFileName();

return targetPath;
}
```

FULL CODE HERE

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout, $cordovaFileTransfer, $sce) {

//Gets the URL of where to download from
$scope.getURL = function () {

    //Whatever URL we want
    var url = "http://static.videogular.com/assets/videos/videogular.mp4";
    return url;


}


//Gets the filename of any URL we download from
$scope.getFileName = function () {


    //Splits the URL
    var filename = scope.getURL().split("/").pop();

    return filename;


}


//This function is used to get the directory path so we can use it for other functions
$scope.getFilePath = function () {

    //Use this code for internal file download
    var targetPath = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory + scope.getFileName();

    return targetPath;
}

//download file function
$scope.downloadFile = function () {
    //Keeps track of progress bar
    var statusDom = document.querySelector('#status');
    var myProgress = document.querySelector("#myProgress");
    //URL where the video is downloaded from
    //var url = "http://static.videogular.com/assets/videos/videogular.mp4";
    //Splits the URL
   // var filename = url.split("/").pop();
    //alert(filename);

    //Interal storage
    //Use this code for internal file download
    var targetPath = scope.getFilePath();


    var trustHosts = true
    var options = {};

    //Makes sure that the URL is trusted to get around permission issues at download
    console.log($sce.trustAsResourceUrl(scope.getURL()));
  $cordovaFileTransfer.download(scope.getURL(), scope.getFilePath(), options, trustHosts)
      .then(function (result) {
          // Success!
          alert(JSON.stringify(result));
      }, function (error) {
          // Error
          alert(JSON.stringify(error));
      }, function (progress) {

          //Shows how much the file has loaded
          if (progress.lengthComputable) {
              var perc = Math.floor(progress.loaded / progress.total * 100);
              statusDom.innerHTML = perc + "% loaded...";
              myProgress.value = perc;
          } else {
              if (statusDom.innerHTML == "") {
                  statusDom.innerHTML = "Loading";
              } else {
                  statusDom.innerHTML += ".";
              }
          }
      })

}
})
```

If anyone could please show me the correct way to call these functions in angularjs that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why you use "scope" instead of '$scope"? What console will say if  you use $scope.getURL() and $scope.getFilePath()?

Comment: Yeah I realise my mistake now, I think for some reason I thought it was ignoring the $ character on some previous testing but it's working fine now with $scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing several `$`s when attempting to access $scope from within $scope functions.

```
$scope.something = function () {
  //This is the scope
  console.log($scope);

  //This is undefined
  console.log(scope);
}
```

You may be confusing Dependency Injection (like $scope, $http, etc in controllers) with directive's link function parameters, which are strictly ordered (scope, element, attributes, controller).

Comment: Thank you, your example explained my errors perfectly! My app is now functioning as expected